# Passing through data frames into functions and into ggplot by column

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I'm trying to do my first function in R.  I have a dataframe of inderminate columns, and I want to create a ggplot of each set of columns.  For example, columns, 1&2, 1&3, 1&4 etc.

However, when I try the following function I get the object not found error, but only when we get the the ggplot portion.

Thanks,

```
BrandPlot=function(Brand){
  NoCol=ncol(Brand)
  count=2
  while (count<=NoCol){
   return(ggplot(Brand, aes(x=Brand[,1], y=Brand[,count]))+geom_point())
    count=(count+1)
  }
}
```

To clarify,

I'm trying to get the effect (also, I plan on adding additional things like geom_smooth()  but I want to get it working first

```
ggplot(Brand, aes(x=Brand[,1], y=Brand[,2]))+geom_point
ggplot(Brand, aes(x=Brand[,1], y=Brand[,3]))+geom_point
ggplot(Brand, aes(x=Brand[,1], y=Brand[,4]))+geom_point
ggplot(Brand, aes(x=Brand[,1], y=Brand[,5]))+geom_point
```

(also, I plan on adding additional things like geom_smooth()  )  but I want to get it working first

Comment: Are you trying to do a function here?  It sounds like you may want to melt the data, then add a facet_wrap function

Comment: And note if I switch ggplot to plot, the code works just fine.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Did you try editing the code below to your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Per the note above, something like this may be what you're looking for...

```
brandplot <- function(x){
    require(reshape2)
    require(ggplot2)

    x_melt <- melt(x, id.vars = names(x)[1])

    ggplot(x_melt, 
           aes_string(x = names(x_melt)[1], 
                      y = 'value', 
                      group = 'variable')) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap( ~ variable)
}

dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10, 25, T),
                  b = sample(20:30, 25, T),
                  c = sample(40:50, 25, T))

brandplot(dat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Note: @maloneypatr's solution is a better way to use `ggplot` for your application].

To answer your question directly, there are a couple of problems.

1. Your function returns after the first run through the loop (e.g., `count=2`), so you will never get more than one plot from this.
2. `ggplot` evaluates arguments to `aes(...)` *in the context of the data frame defined in `data=...`*, so it is looking for something like `Brand$Brand` (e.g., a column named `Brand` in the dataframe `Brand`). Since there is no such column, you get the *Object not found* error.

The following code will generate a series of `n-1` plots where `n = ncol(Brand)`.

```
BrandPlot=function(Brand){
  for (count in 2:ncol(Brand)){
    ggp <- ggplot(Brand, aes_string(x=names(Brand)[1], y=names(Brand)[count]))
    ggp <- ggp + geom_point()
    ggp <- ggp + ggtitle(paste(names(Brand)[count], " vs. ", names(Brand)[1]))
    plot(ggp)
  }
}
```

Comment: So I need to use the "names" function for it to know.  Got it.  Thanks so much.  I'm curious though why I can call it that way outside of a function.  And it works with regular plot.

Comment: I looked into this some more, and it appears that ggplot does not recognize the variable `count` defined in the function. However, if you define `count` in the calling environment, ggplot finds it. So it looks like ggplot first looks for a column count, as in `Brand$count`, and not finding that seeks a count variable in the environment from which the function was called. Very strange. Bottom line: if at all possible, only use column names in `aes(...)`. The `plot(...)` function in base R works completely differently. There is no equivalent to `aes(...)`.